# DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance uses wrong local time format with android 5

Tags: android, localization

I'm using the following code to format my output:

```
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT);
    Date date = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyContentProvider.KEY_TIME_START)));
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.column_time_start);
    textView.setText(df.format(date));
```

For e.g. German I would expect the local 24 hour time format.

With Android 4 (e.g. 4.4.2) the time is well formated as expected.

But with Android 5 (e.g. 5.1) the time is formated with 12 hour time format.

Does someone know a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you considered using _android.text.format.DateFormat_? It should take user preference into account.

Comment: It works:
`textView.setText(getDateFormat(context).format(date) + " " + getTimeFormat(context).format(date));`But now I have to format date and time successively. Is there another solution?

Comment: `DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())`seems to be bugy since Android 5 :-(
And `getTimeFormat(context)` is called unfortunately without the style parameter.

Comment: I got the same problem: as a programmer AND a user! My Oxygen OS 2.1 is based on Android 5.1 and all apps like Facebook, FitBit AND MY OWN - produce the wrong 12-hour-format even though I set 24-hours here in Germany as my format. Why is nobody really following up on this bug?

Answer (score 3):

Try this using `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(int, int, Locale)`:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = dateFormat .format(new Date());
```

If this isn't working for you try something like this:

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
// Find out what the current locale is and format your date based on that
```

Comment: Does not solve the problem. The output looks same like before.

Comment: @samo See the edit please. It'll be more manual work on your part, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. `android.text.format.DateFormat`works (see above).